# What is the best way to alter a native browser event?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to temporary modify the `currentTarget` property of an event with vanilla javascript.

My main goals would be to have a very fast implementation as events fire rapidly, 
 and not to change the original event or at least to revert the original event back to it's original state once the operation is done.

Unfortunately prototype inheritance fails with `Illegal invocation` (chrome) or `'get currentTarget' called on an object that does not implement interface Event.` (firefox) or `The Event.currentTarget getter can only be used on instances of Event` (safari) errors:

```js
// Trigger event for demonstration 
// in a real scenario that would be caused by a user
var event = new Event('demo');
document.documentElement.addEventListener('demo', eventHandler1, false);
document.documentElement.addEventListener('demo', eventHandler2, false);
document.documentElement.addEventListener('demo', eventHandler3, false);
document.documentElement.dispatchEvent(event);

// The event handlers:
function eventHandler1(event) {
  event.currentTarget = 'MyCustomValue';
  console.log(1, event.type, event.currentTarget); // <- won't output MyCustomValue
}

function eventHandler2(event) {
  try {
    var clone = Object.create(event);
    clone.currentTarget = 'MyCustomValue';
    console.log(2, event.type, clone.currentTarget);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(2, e.message); // <- will log an Illegal invocation error
  }
}

function eventHandler3(event) {
  var Clone = function() {
    this.currentTarget = 'MyCustomValue';
  };
  Clone.prototype = event;
  try {
    var clone = new Clone();
    console.log(3, event.type, clone.currentTarget);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(3, e.message); // <- will log an Illegal invocation error
  }
}
```

For modern browsers we could use a `Proxy` object however I would love to find a solution which supports IE11.

Do you have any hints how this might be implemented with vanilla javascript?

Comment: Why not just use composition ? You could have your event wrap the original one and act as a decorator when needed. As it would let you use your own prototype, this would be very light.

Comment: @DenysSéguret sounds nice - could you provide an example for that? I have one concern: Wouldn't it be very slow to execute all getters although they might not be used?

Comment: An example ? I mean a new class with `constructor(e){ this.original=e }` and all non specific methods of the class just being decorator functions (meaning they just call the same method of `this.original`). Thanks to modern engines it shouldn't be slower than using the original event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Concept:

The first example doesn't work because you are trying to override the `currentTarget` value using assignment, the value won't actually get overriden as there is no setter for `currentTarget`, there is only a getter.

As for the second and third examples, the error is thrown because you are calling `currentTarget` on the wrong object (**i.e.** the `this` will be the clone not the original event).

To work around this, just shadow the getter itself (which resides in the prototype) with a new getter or property attached to the instance `event` using `Object.defineProperty` instead of assignment:

**Example:**

```js
var event = new Event('demo');
document.documentElement.addEventListener('demo', eventHandler, false);
document.documentElement.dispatchEvent(event);

function eventHandler(event) {
  Object.defineProperty(event, "currentTarget", {
    value: "MyCustomValue"
  });

  console.log(event.type, event.currentTarget);
}
```

### Ability to revert back:

As the new property is assigned to the instance itself and not to its prototype (in other words, the new property is shadowing the getter in the prototype), we can just delete it afterwards to revert back. But to do so we have to make it configurable, otherwise we won't be able to delete it:

```
Object.defineProperty(event, "currentTarget", {
  value: "MyCustomValue",
  configurable: true
});
```

Se when we want to revert, we'll just delete it as follow:

```
delete event.currentTarget;
```

**Example:**

```js
var event = new Event('demo');
document.documentElement.addEventListener('demo', eventHandler, false);
document.documentElement.dispatchEvent(event);

function eventHandler(event) {
  console.log("Original: ", event.type, event.currentTarget);

  Object.defineProperty(event, "currentTarget", {
    value: "MyCustomValue",
    configurable: true
  });

  console.log("After overriding:", event.type, event.currentTarget);

  delete event.currentTarget;

  console.log("After reverting:", event.type, event.currentTarget);
}
```

### Note:

You can also make `currentTarget` a getter instead of a property and it will work too:

```
Object.defineProperty(event, "currentTarget", {
  get: function() { return "MyCustomValue"; },
  configurable: true
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to revert to the original getter afterwards?

Comment: Wow that's pretty amazing! :)

Comment: @jantimon Yeah. Such a long answer to basically just tell you that doing `event.currentTarget = something` is assigning `something` to the getter's returned value. :P